# AWS transfer family service for transferring files over sftp to remote sftp server(outbound traffic only!!)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-transfer-family, aws-sftp

I have a requirement to send 4mb file uploaded by our EC2 instance on S3 to remote SFTP server.

We don’t need to receive any inbound SFTP traffic.

I explored AWS transfer family and came across SFTP connector.

I need to know since I am doing only outbound SFTP data transfer from S3 to to remote SFTP server, do I still need any SFTP enabled endpoint ?

If I include SFTP enabled endpoint in pricing calculator the monthly bill goes above 200$.

What will be the final pricing for a month in this scenario ?

Comment: You could disable and enable the SFTP connector to save some money (though, note it does take some time to provision the connector everytime, so even if you need to use it for 30 seconds a day, you'll need 10-30 minutes to provision it).  Honestly, I'd just create a Lambda with a SFTP library of some sort to do the work, given the small workload here.

Comment: How did you calculate the $200 charge?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I went to pricing calculator : [link](https://calculator.aws/#/createCalculator/TransferFamily) . Entered details: Select the protocol(s) enabled on your endpoints: SFTP, Total number of endpoints with SFTP enabled: 1, Data downloaded per month over SFTP: 120 mb. Total price is shown: 219$. I want to understand if I need to select 1 SFTP enabled endpoint for our scenario.

Comment: You have calculated the cost for "Endpoints for file sharing", but if you want to do only outbound SFTP data transfer from S3 to a remote SFTP server, then you instead want "Connectors to externally hosted servers". This connector is not on that pricing calculator.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thank you so much!! Do you think if it is reasonable to use SFTP connectors for our use case where only ~120 mb data will be transferred. Wouldn't it make more sense to call SFTP server from my EC2 instance ?

Comment: Yes, it would be cheaper from an EC2 instance (just a Data Transfer charges of 9c/GB, plus your EC2 costs).

Answer (score 0):

You say that you are "doing only outbound SFTP data transfer from S3 to to remote SFTP server".

This would use the "AWS Transfer SFTP connectors". From [Managed File Transfer—AWS Transfer Family Pricing – Amazon Web Services](https://aws.amazon.com/aws-transfer-family/pricing/):

> AWS Transfer SFTP connectors
> SFTP connectors are used to **connect to remote SFTP servers** and transfer files directly to or from Amazon S3. With SFTP connectors, **you do not pay AWS Data Transfer fees** -- you only pay the fee listed below:
>
> - Cost per connector call: `$0.001 per connector call`
> - Cost per GB of data transfer: `$0.40 per GB sent or retrieved`

Note that there is **no timing-based charge** (that is, no monthly charge). You are only charged for the connection and the amount of data transferred.